# Prestashop fields_options in AdminMaintenanceController

Tags: forms, prestashop, backoffice

In my override file AdminMaintenanceController, I try to add an input file to add an image(dynamically) on maintenance.tpl when the maintenance mode in active. The field form appear correctly in my backoffice below maintenance ip and switch but nothing is uploaded.

Do you have tips or informations about this issue ?

I'm on 1.6

My controller:

```
class AdminMaintenanceController extends AdminMaintenanceControllerCore
{
public function __construct()
{
    $this->bootstrap = true;
    $this->className = 'Configuration';
    $this->table = 'configuration';

    parent::__construct();


    $this->fields_options = array(
        'general' => array(
            'title' =>    $this->l('General'),
            'fields' =>    array(
                'PS_SHOP_ENABLE' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Enable Shop'),
                    'desc' => $this->l('Activate or deactivate your shop (It is a good idea to deactivate your shop while you perform maintenance. Please note that the webservice will not be disabled).'),
                    'validation' => 'isBool',
                    'cast' => 'intval',
                    'type' => 'bool'
                ),
                'PS_MAINTENANCE_IP' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Maintenance IP'),
                    'hint' => $this->l('IP addresses allowed to access the front office even if the shop is disabled. Please use a comma to separate them (e.g. 42.24.4.2,127.0.0.1,99.98.97.96)'),
                    'validation' => 'isGenericName',
                    'type' => 'maintenance_ip',
                    'default' => ''
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array('title' => $this->l('Save'))
        ),

        'image' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Images parameters'),
            'fields' => array(
                'PS_IMG1' => array(
                    'title' => $this->l('Left side image'),
                    'type' => 'file',
                    'name' => 'PS_IMG1',
                    'thumb' => _PS_IMG_.'PS_IMG1.jpg',
                    'hint' => $this->l('Choose the photo for this side'),
                ),
            ),
            'submit' => array('title' => $this->l('Save'))
        ),
```

Comment: It seems that you have implemented only a form fields display but not file(image) upload process. You need to instantiate a process of an image uploading after form confirmation

Comment: Yes, with a postProcess function and ImageManager class, it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have implemented only a form fields display but not file(image) upload process. You need to instantiate a process of an image uploading after form confirmation

Comment: Yes, with a postProcess function and ImageManager class, it works !